# Styles conflict of bootstrap-buttons and links

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I used tag `<%= link_to "Sign up!", signup_path, class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>` in my ERB-tempate. It's link but with button design.

I use bootstrap, but change default colors of buttons.

The problem is that I setuped colors of links in my scss file. And color of links = color of buttons background.

In other places it's good because text and links usually are on the white background. Also I haven't problems when I use button as usual submit button in forms.

But problem ***only with this*** button.

This button, when I use styles of buttons and links:

[image: https://image.ibb.co/b4qqAV/2018-11-21-21-28-08-2.png]

(when mouse over and click - text appears)

This button, when I deleted styles of links:

[image: https://image.ibb.co/nCNOxA/2018-11-21-21-28-08.png]

I want to make this button in purple with white text and preserve other links in purple.

What should I do to solve this problem?

Part of my file is here:

*/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss*

```css
/* constants */
$bgDefault:   #9b59b6;
$bgHighlight: #8e44ad;
$bgHover:     #7f4496;
$bgActive:    #633575;
$bgDisabled:  #b07ec4;
$colHover:    #333;

/* buttons */
.btn-primary {
  background-color: $bgDefault;
  border-color: $bgHighlight;
    &:hover {
      background-color: $bgHover;
      border-color: $bgHighlight;
    }
    &:active, &:focus, &:active:hover, &:active:focus {
      background-color: $bgActive;
      border-color: $bgHighlight;
    }
}

.btn-primary.disabled {
  background-color: $bgDisabled;
  border-color: $bgHighlight;
}

.btn-primary.disabled:hover, .btn-primary.disabled:focus,
.btn-primary.disabled.focus, .btn-primary[disabled]:hover,
.btn-primary[disabled]:focus, .btn-primary[disabled].focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:hover, fieldset[disabled]
.btn-primary:focus, fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary.focus {
  background-color: $bgDisabled;
  border-color: $bgHighlight;
}

/* links */
a {
  color: $bgDefault;
  &:visited {
    color: $bgDefault;
     }
  &:active {
    color: $bgActive;
  }
  &:hover {
    color: $colHover;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found decision. This bug because this link was **visited**.

I added this code:

```
.btn:visited { 
  color: #fff
}
```

Now it works.

Perhaps it will be helpful for somebody.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to explicitly set the color of the text in your buttons. Try this:

```
 .btn-primary {
   color: white;
 }
```

Comment: Doesn't work this way. Text in submit button is white without this code. Problem only with link as button

Comment: `.btn:visited { color: #fff }` helps